# Why are these two API methods generating a conflict

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

We are developing an MVC4 API application and have run across a strange issue that we have no explanation for.

The API controller has two methods:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [AcceptVerbs("Post", "Get")]
    public ArtifactContent Post(string userName, string password, string id) ...
```

and

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string userName, string password, string id, EnumType contentType) ...
```

Although the two methods clearly have different method signatures, we are getting the following error message:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Multiple
>   actions were found that match the request:
>   [XXX].Models.ArtifactContent **Post(System.String, System.String,
>   System.String)** on type
>   [XXX].API.ArtifactContentController\r\nSystem.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
>   **Get(System.String, System.String, System.String, ArtifactContentTypes)** on type
>   [XXX].API.ArtifactContentController","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

We can work around the error by making one of these two changes, but I really want to know *why* .NET is throwing the error when the two signature are *clearly* different:

1. Remove the `Get` `AcceptVerbs` attribute from the `Post` method
2. Change the signature of the `Get` method to accept the Enum as an integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known behavior/issue/bug in `ASP.NET Web API`.

In short, the action selector (`IHttpActionSelector`), will not take into account `Enums` when trying to match the incoming HTTP request to a relevant action inside the controller.

The reason is by default only primitive types (i.e. `int`, `string` etc) are picked from `RouteData` to find a matching action. `Enum` is not one of those, so it's ignored and therefore, even though your actions have different signatures from the compiler perspective, in the eyes of the action selector they are identical.

You can track the progress of the potential fix here - http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/312

For the time being, as you said yourself, the best workaround is to pass `enum` as `int` or `string` (and cast to `enum`).